# ADFS is gving error when redirection is made to main application

Tags: azure, adfs

I am creating one azure application which has 2 web roles. One web role is normal web application and other one has ADFS integrated with it. The web role (ASFS one) redirects the user to the first web role after authentication to continue the normal application flow. I am getting following error when I am redirecting to the first web role from the ADFS web role.

> Unable to find assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I have made CopyLocal true, in case if the dll is not available. But, the same issue is observed after that.
Can anybody tell me what is the issue here?
Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer for this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/kk-KZ/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/35d37b41-b638-4023-aaab-b8134ac27278?prof=required